# mathematics of version control systems

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Has anyone written a paper on the mathematics of version control systems? 
The background for this question: Many people are now studying the mathematics of computer systems.
However, one aspect of computer systems is that they evolve over time, due to expanded demands from users or other reasons such as, mundanely, fixing bugs.
In the real world of managing those systems, a significant amount of effort goes in tracking those changes. The mathematics of evolving systems should be of interest, and susceptible to analysis from, say, topos theory.
A good place to start such analysis would be to analyze the math of version control systems.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to read up on [the theory behind the Darcs DVCS](http://darcs.net/Theory). The linked-to page also includes links to papers such as "Homotopical Patch Theory" (by Carlo Angiuli, Ed Morehouse, Daniel R. Licata and Robert Harper) and "A Categorical Theory of Patches" (by Samuel Mimram and Cinzia Di Giusto).

Comment: The published version of the Mimram-Di-Giusto paper "A Categorical Theory of Patches" is at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2013.09.018